# Your Second iOS app Tutorial: How Many Sections Do They Want?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

In Your Second iOS app, there is a portion that says the following:

> After you finish laying out the cells in the table, the detail scene should look similar to this:
>
> [image: detail_scene_design]

However, mine has Section-1, Section-2, Section-3 right above each section. I get the feeling that they want 1 section with three cells.

Can you tell which?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Gilles :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You incremented the number of sections by mistake instead of incrementing the number of rows. Which you should have done.

**Edited to add**

You get to this by highlighting the Table View Section in the controller scene and editing the  number of rows in the right hand panel.

I picture makes this clearer:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 3;
}
```

This should be your code to have 3 rows and only 1 section like that of image

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to the image its 1 section with 3 rows. In `numberOfSections` method return 1 and in `numberOfRowsInSection` method return 3.

Answer (score 1):

They are looking for one section with three cells.